# How to add an additional column to the result set returned by a SP without modifying the SP?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a Stored Procedure (SP), named `myStoredProcedure`, returning me such output based on `startDate` and `endDate` user-defined parameters:

```
PrimaryName  SecondaryName  Volume
    A             B           20
    C             D           30
    A             D           50
    ...
```

So, Volume represents the sum of all the cases between the dates defined.

In another SP, named `mySecondStoredProcedure`, I am using the first SP to get the result there. However, my problem is that I need an additional attribute in my output, which is `year`, I want to see year based volumes. Therefore, the output I would like to see is something like that

*assume* `startDate: 2014, endDate: 2015`:

```
PrimaryName  SecondaryName  Volume   Year
    A             B           12      2014
    C             D           14      2014
    A             D           20      2014
    A             B           8       2015
    C             D           16      2015
    A             D           30      2015
    ...
```

I am not allowed to modify `myStoredProcedure`. Therefore I build a `while` loop in the second SP to receive it. My code is like:

```
declare @temp_table table
(
  PrimaryGroup varchar(10),
  SecondaryGroup varchar(10),
  Volume int
)

while @startDate < @endDate
begin
   insert into @temp_table
   exec myStoredProcedure @startDate @endDate

   set @startDate = DATEADD(YEAR,1,@startDate)
end

select * from @temp_table
```

This is giving me the result without the `year` column. I need a `year` column like I showed in my example output above. I could not find a way to add it. There is no primary key in the result set returned by `myStoredProcedure`. Also, SQL Server 2008 does not let me add a `year` column in `@temp_table`, saying that fields are not matching. How can I add the `year` column properly? Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: When I add `year` column in the definition of @temp_table, the error I receive: `Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close with the syntax you currently have, you'll just need to add the `year` to the temp table and supply it after calling the stored procedure.  In addition, you will also need to specify the columns being inserted (a practice well worth getting in the habit of) as your procedure doesn't return the same number of columns.

```
declare @temp_table table
(
  PrimaryGroup varchar(10),
  SecondaryGroup varchar(10),
  Volume int,
  Year int
)

while @startDate < @endDate
begin
   insert into @temp_table (PrimaryGroup, SecondaryGroup, Volume)
   exec myStoredProcedure @startDate @endDate

   Update   @temp_table
   Set      Year = @StartDate
   Where    Year Is Null

   set @startDate = DATEADD(YEAR,1,@startDate)
end

select * from @temp_table
```

Comment: When I add Year column in declaration, the error I get: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Comment: @ErayBalkanli You need to modify your `INSERT` statement to include the columns you're inserting.  Note the `(PrimaryGroup, SecondaryGroup, Volume)` portion of the `INSERT` statement in my answer.

Comment: Oh, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Add a Year column to your temp table, and apply the structured insert

```
declare @temp_table table
(
  PrimaryGroup varchar(10),
  SecondaryGroup varchar(10),
  Volume int,
  Year  int
)

while @startDate < @endDate
begin
   insert into @temp_table (PrimaryName,SecondaryName,Volume)
   exec myStoredProcedure @startDate @endDate

   Update @temp_table set Year = @startDate where Year is Null

   set @startDate = DATEADD(YEAR,1,@startDate)
end

select * from @temp
```

Comment: When I add Year as a column, the error I am getting: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Comment: @ErayBalkanli did you add (PrimaryName,SecondaryName,Volume) to your insert statement?

Comment: Oh, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Create a second table variable that will hold the result:

```
declare @result_table table
(
  Year int,
  PrimaryGroup varchar(10),
  SecondaryGroup varchar(10),
  Volume int
)
```

Then in the `while` loop after fetching the result into `@temp_table`:

```
insert into @result_table
    select <year>, PrimaryGroup, SecondaryGroup, Volume from @temp_table;

truncate @temp_table;
```